How to generate a combined type from the values of a dictionary?
Let's say I have
const myDict = {
  a: "Foo",
  b: "Bar"
} as const;

I would like to obtain the type type MyType = "Foo" | "Bar" given myDict.
I know this is possible when instead of myDict I have a list:
const myList = ["Foo", "Bar"];

// Yay!
type MyType = typeof myList[number]

but no idea how to make this out of the dict values without looping through the dictionary and creating such a list.

Hint: lookup keyof

You could use a reusable generic type:
Playground
const myDict = {
  a: "Foo",
  b: "Bar"
} as const;

type Values<T extends object> = T[keyof T];

type DictValues = Values<typeof myDict>; //  "Foo" | "Bar"


Note: The original question was missing the as const in addition to the keyof.

For the values, retrieve the keys with keyof and pass them back to the object. And use as const to get specific types like "Foo" and "Bar" instead of the generic string type.

What does the "as const" mean in TypeScript and what is its use case? - StackOverflow answer
keyof type operator - TypeScript Docs

const myDict = {
  a: "Foo",
  b: "Bar",
} as const

// typeof myDict --> { "a": "Foo", "b": "Bar" }
// keyof typeof myDict --> "a" | "b"
type MyType = typeof myDict[keyof typeof myDict] // "Foo" | "Bar"

Without as const just return generic types:
const myDict = {
  a: "Foo", // string
  b: 123, // number
}

// typeof myDict --> { "a": string, "b": number }
// keyof typeof myDict --> "a" | "b"
type MyType = typeof myDict[keyof typeof myDict] // string | number

And now that the logic is clear, you can simplify it so you don't have to write typeof myDict twice. To do this, follow Alexander Nenashev's answer:
const myDict = {
  a: "Foo",
  b: "Bar",
} as const

// T will be typeof myDict --> { "a": "Foo", "b": "Bar" }
// keyof T will be keyof typeof myDict --> "a" | "b"
type Values<T extends object> = T[keyof T]
type MyType = Values<typeof myDict> // "Foo" | "Bar"


In TypeScript, what does <T> mean? - StackOverflow answer

Related

Utility type for T[keyof T] or new keyword valueof - GitHub: microsoft/typescript #37642
Add KeyOf and ValueOf definitions to built-in lib - GitHub: microsoft/typescript #31438
Is there a valueof similar to keyof in TypeScript? - StackOverflow

